# IOS runtime error -Foundation.MonoTouchException has been thrown

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

here is the error  I am getting :
Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell_id - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

now I doing what this guy is doing :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRTbOZSqSNA&t=618s

only he is not getting my error and I have no idea why...
here is my code :

```
 public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = (ScheduleCell) t 
       TableView.DequeueReusableCell("cell_id", indexPath);
        var school1 = school[indexPath.Row];
        cell.Updatecell(school1);
        cell.TextLabel.Text = school[indexPath.Row].Site;
        return cell;
    }
```

I did remember to add the idenitier just like that guy in the video.. so IDK why it is not working
it does nor throw that error if I remove indexPath... but if I do then I get another error on update.
saying System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object

and I do have data in there
how do I fix this ?

Comment: have you given cell identifier in storyboard?

Comment: yes just like the guy did in the youtube video. I really do not understand how i clearly works for him but not me and I did everything he did.

Comment: It seems like you forgot set identifier  on Cell in storyboard , or the `identifier  `in code is not the same as the value in storyboard. If the error still exists, could you provide a simple demo to us for the troubleshooting?